# Problem with embedding netlogoweb html files in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, netlogo

Hello I am using Rmarkdown to build netlogo tutorials but I have a problem
When I embed a netlogoweb html file ( a running netlogo model) rmarkdown only show "one quarter2 of the netlogo world model

the code I use in Rmarkdown is  the following:

```
htmltools::includeHTML("AvionesGo.html")
```

I expect to see the following applet:

![html applet]https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5w3u0e33zujnx0/FileEmbeddedInChrome.PNG?dl=0

but the applet seen in Rmarkdown (Netlogo world) is only one quarter of the original:

![rmarkdown applet]https://www.dropbox.com/s/gspjv78s7gy5wv2/FileEmbeddedInRMarkDown.PNG?dl=0

The file (AvionesGo.html) I am embedding is the following html file generated by netLogoWeb:

Click [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfccggham6faedo/AvionesGo.html?dl=0)

Thanks for your Help

Comment: I think the knitr::include_url might work. I am having some sort of bug where it only tells gives me a message "Error in enc2utf8(x) : argument is not a character vector" when I try it, but you could give it a shot.

Comment: I will try include_url thanks for your help